# How implement a custom arrayadapter with checkboxs

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to implement a custom array adapter to add as a content of my fragment but I haven't found a good documentation on how create it.

How can I doa custom arrayadapter with checkboxs?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you understand array adapters? This isn't a we do the work for you site

Comment: Try looking a tutorial like http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429, or http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/, or http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/ and then come back with a specific question

Comment: This site is ridiculous sometime and all of you that are trying to be the moderators too. My question is very clear and my experience with array adapters doesn't count by the way is basic which is the reason because I am asking for guidance and some kind of documentation in my question. This forum has some good answers but to much censure for questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: 
[listview with checkboxes](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

Comment: This answer should be in comment. You're just providing a link without explanation

Comment: It's an answer. The explanation is in the link! But sorry anyway stackoverflow police!

Comment: THANK THIS IS GOOD DOCUMENTATION IT HELP TO UNDERSTAND THE CODE AND IMPLEMENT IT. THIS PEOPLE HAS TOO MUCH CENSURA ON EVERYTHING THAT IS POSTED HERE IT INCREDIBLE. BUT THANK YOU AGAIN YOUR LINK HELP A LOT

Comment: You are welcome @Tecsined. Yes, it is very difficult to reach the points that you need to comment questions, they are always searching for things to downvote! Nice codings, cheers *